# Set order number in sequence of checkbox checked in php + javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, checkbox, sequence

I'm getting some problems trying to set order number if sequence of checkbox checked with javascript:

```
<?php
    for ($x=0; $x<count($UnidadesServicio); $x++){
        $idunidadserv = $UnidadesServicio[$x]['idunidadserv'];
        $unidadserv = utf8_encode($UnidadesServicio[$x]['lugarunidad']);
        $desunidad = utf8_encode($UnidadesServicio[$x]['desunidad']);
?>  

<tr>
  <td width="10%"><input type="checkbox" id="cbx_<?php echo $idunidadserv;?>" name="chk_unidadserv" value="<?php echo $idunidadserv;?>" onClick="AgregarUnidadServ()" /></td>

    <td width="56%" height="28"> <?php echo $unidadserv;?> </td>
    <td width="13%">&nbsp;</td>
  <td width="21%" align="center"> <input name="txt_orden_<?php echo $x;?>" type="text" id="txt_orden_<?php echo $idunidadserv;?>" value="" size="2" maxlength="1" class="txtorden" /> </td>

</tr>

<?php
    }
?>
```

My JavaScript function:

```
<script>

function AgregarUnidadServ(){
   var group = document.getElementsByName('chk_unidadserv');
   var i;
   for (i=0; i<group.length; i++){
      if (group[i].checked == true){
         var id = parseFloat(i+1);
         $("#txt_orden_"+id).val(i);    
      }
   }
}

</script>
```

What i need to to do:
[image]

When check any checkbox, set in `input text` the sequence number (1, 2, 3, etc.)

That code, display like this:

[image]

Greetings.

Comment: and what error did you get?

Comment: I edited, sorry for bad english.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Where order number are storing?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#txt_orden_"+id).val(id);
```

And sequence will start from **1**.